# /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied Jenkins slave on ecs cluster

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-ecs

I'm using the AWS EC2 plugin for Jenkins to spawn up Jenkins slaves when tasks are generated. Running into permission issues when trying to build docker inside docker container. I've looked at dozens of other posts and people frequently provide this as the answer:

1. create docker group
2. add jenkins user to docker group
3. restart
4. everything magically works

The thing is is that I can't restart, because the jenkins slave gets spawned using the plugin, and I'm not sure how to restart it properly for it to handle the build correctly upon restart. Also, that would mean to run the restart on the host despite being in a container which sounds like a bad idea.

I've tried:

1. Adding jenkins to sudo users in dockerfile `RUN adduser jenkins
   sudo` followed by `RUN echo "jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" >>
   /etc/sudoers`
2. Changing docker socket file owner `RUN chown root:jenkins /var/run/docker.sock`
3. Changing docker socket permissions `chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock`
4. Using `newgrp` so I don't have to restart docker from outside the container

Basically, how do I get around not restarting the docker service while also providing sudo permissions in order to build dockerfiles inside jenkins slave container? Or if I can actually restart while still using EC2 plugin, how would I best go about that?

Current dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins/jnlp-slave

USER root

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install apt-transport-https \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        gnupg2 \
        software-properties-common && \
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID")/gpg > /tmp/dkey; apt-key add /tmp/dkey && \
    add-apt-repository \
      "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID") \
      $(lsb_release -cs) \
      stable" && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install docker-ce && \
    apt-get -y install sudo

VOLUME /var/run/docker.sock

RUN adduser jenkins sudo

RUN echo "jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins

RUN chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock

RUN chown root:jenkins /var/run/docker.sock

USER jenkins
```

Thank you!

Comment: Will be nice to see ```docker run``` command

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the `docker run` command is for the slave since it's handled by the plugin, but I imagine it's something similar to `docker run jenkins/jnlp-slave -url http://jenkins-server:port <secret> <agent name>`

Comment: You can use a similar technique from this to setup Jenkins agents with access to the docker socket: https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/jenkins-docker

Comment: Usually, we do not install docker to the container, we install docker on the host instead and mount docker client exe and docker socket into jenkins container.  This means all docker commands run on host and not into the container... Then ```sudo docker ...``` works fine...

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced this issue I have to do below steps for it to work:

1. Update the docker file to install the docker-client.
2. Update the ECS Cloud Jenkins configuration to do volumen mount i.e `/var/run/docker.sock`
3. The most essential part is to run the docker commands inside the container. There are two options:

   i. run the containerUser as `root` user.
     this is the most convenient step if running the container as root user if fine to you

   ii. add jenkins user to the docker group on the host

   `usermod -a -G docker jenkins`

   Get the gid of the docker group and map the gid inside the container. Update the gid of the docker container to the gid of the host. This way you won't get the `permission denied` error and don't need to do `chown 777 /var/run/docker.sock`